# Will WaitHandle.WaitAny also reset other handles than the returned?

Tags: .net, synchronization

The .NET framework method `WaitHandle.WaitAny(WaitHandle[])` waits on multiple handles and returns if any of them was set. The return value is the index of the set handle from the passed array.

If the handle is an `AutoResetEvent`, it will automatically reset when somebody waited for it and is now unblocked.

If multiple handles are set while waiting, will `WaitAny` also consume and reset the other signals or will the other handles remain set and will it return the other index when I call it next time? If it resets all handles, how can I know that other handles were also set and not miss them? I'm trying not to use a `ManualResetEvent` in this situation because more signals might be coming in while I'm still realising that a signal has been set and just start processing the data.

Comment: It is unspecified.  Don't do it, there's no point to it.  Getting more MREs signaled while you are past the WaitAny() call should never be a problem.  If it is then you are doing it wrong.